# Extend function defined on triangle vertexs continuously?

Tags: gradient

I have a triangle ABC in 2D space, and have defined f(A), f(B), and 
f(C), where f is a real valued function. Questions:

- Can I extend f to be defined on the entire triangle such that f is 
  continuous?
- If yes, is the solution unique?
- If not, can I find an f that's smooth (infinitely differentiable) 
  inside the triangle?

f needn't be defined outside the triangle (thus, it's OK if f isn't 
continuous/differentiable at the vertexs/edges)

Goal: I want to assign rainbow colors (saturation and value both 100%, 
varying hue) to the three points of a triangle, and the color the 
triangle "naturally".

Comment: This is more maths than programming, but its fairly interesting. If you think of hue as height it intuitively seems likely.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. Yes, it seems there must be such a function, but I'm not sure it's unique. I tried something like looking at how far a point was from A,B,C and weighting based on that, but couldn't quite get it to work.